# validating a string in Java returns incorrectly. Testing for length of string from scanner?

Tags: java

String validation issue:

This method works for the most part, but theres some apparent logic problem. If a user hits enter at the console with no input, it should return the "Error! this entry required" message, but it doesnt. I would have imagined it would, since I am testing for an input of
one or less chars

```
public String getChoiceString(String prompt, String s1, String s2) {
    this.println(prompt);
    String userChoice = this.sc.next();
    String i;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(s1) || userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(s2))
        {
            isValid = true;
        }
        else if (userChoice.length() <= 1 || userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            System.out.println("Error! This entry is required. Try again.");
            userChoice = this.sc.next();
        }
        else {
            this.println("Error! Entry must be " + s1 + " or " + s2 + ". Try again.");
            userChoice = this.sc.next();
        }

    }
    return userChoice;
```

From here I create an instance of the class which contains this method. It is called console. I call the methods from this:

```
public class ConsoleTestApp {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Console Tester application");
        System.out.println();

        //get console object
        Console console = IOFactory.getConsoleIO();
        console.println("Int Test");
        console.getIntWithinRange("Enter an integer between -100 and 100: ", -100, 100);
        console.println();
        console.println("Double Test");
        console.getDoubleWithinRange("Enter any number between -100 and 100: ", -100, 100);
        console.println();
        console.println("Required String Test");
        console.getRequiredString("Enter your email address: ");
        console.println();
        console.println("String Choice Test");
        console.getChoiceString("Select one (x/y): ", "x", "y");          
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you give us example inputs for `prompt`, `s1`, and `s2`?

Comment: Also, tell us what the method does.

Comment: So i create an obj called console, and I call the method as: console.getChoiceString("Select one (x/y): ", "x", "y"); the purpose is to make sure the user gets a valid choice based on the choices. If the user enters nothing, it should have an error message to state that the entry is required, and should have a different error if a letter outside the scope of the options is entered.

Comment: But what does it _actually_ do when you just press carriage return?

Comment: It gives a blank line on the console, and waits for input, with nothing new printed.

Comment: So investigate that. (Or see Makoto's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like much of anything happens when you just enter a carriage return with `Scanner#next`.  The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) mandates that it only matches on a complete token with its delimiter.

The default delimiter for `Scanner` is `\p{javaWhitespace}+`.  In essence, it describes a whole token as having at least one whitespace character in it.

Now, let's inspect the empty `String`.  It doesn't contain *any* character in it.  So, if we were going to match against the default delimiter regex, we would fail:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Pattern ptn = sc.delimiter();
System.out.println(ptn);
String empty = "";
String regex = "\\p{javaWhitespace}+";
System.out.println(empty.matches(regex)); // prints false
```

So, the pattern doesn't match, and the `Scanner` will block until it matches something, like `A phrase`.

So, instead of trying to deal with any headache that may be induced from `next()`, what you may be looking to use instead is `nextLine()`.  In most cases, you want to use `nextLine()` when you want to match the entire line of entry, and `next()` when you're processing multiple elements in a single line.

```
String userChoice = this.sc.nextLine(); // wherever this Scanner instance lives...
```

This will match on anything [containing a line separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), and since hitting return/enter will produce that, it will match the entire line you enter, **even if it's a blank line.**